# Making file size-dependent editor (for the same mimetype)

Tags: 14.04, default, default-programs

I have some really large files in my drive as Data. My default editor is gedit. I wish to know if I can change my default editor to something else like say glogg, for files above a certain threshold of size. That is, can I choose my default application depending on the size of file, even the files are of the same format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `desktop` file, and a wrapper script:

1. The `desktop` file

   - Create a desktop file

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/applications/wrapper.desktop
     ```
   - Add the configuration below

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Name=File size dependent editor
     Comment=File size dependent editor
     Exec=/home/user/bin/wrapper %f
     Icon=gedit
     Terminal=false
     Type=Application
     Categories=Editor;
     StartupNotify=true
     MimeType=text/plain;
     ```
   - Replace `user` in `Exec=/home/user/bin/wrapper %f` with your username, the output of

     ```
     echo $USER
     ```
   - Replace the icon name in `Icon=gedit` with a name or path of your choice
   - Use `MimeType=text/plain` to specify the mime types of files for which the decision is to apply. Separate multiple mime types via `;`

     Get the mime type via

     ```
     mimetype your_file
     ```

     e.g. for a text file

     ```
     text/plain
     ```
   - If you want to use a editor with a CLI, like nano, than replace `false` in `Terminal=false` with `true`
2. The wrapper script

   - Create a new script

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/bin
     nano ~/bin/wrapper
     ```
   - Add the code below

     ```
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
     LARGE_FILE_EDITOR="glogg"
     SMALL_FILE_EDITOR="gedit"

     MAX_SMALL_FILE_SIZE=1000000

     FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$1")

     if [ "$FILESIZE" -le $MAX_SMALL_FILE_SIZE ]; then
             "$SMALL_FILE_EDITOR" "$1"
     else
             "$LARGE_FILE_EDITOR" "$1"
     fi
     exit 0
     ```
   - Define your editor for large files in `LARGE_FILE_EDITOR`, e.g. `glogg`
   - Define your editor for small files in `SMALL_FILE_EDITOR`, e.g. `gedit`
   - Define the maximum file size for the `$SMALL_FILE_EDITOR` in `MAX_SMALL_FILE_SIZE`, e.g. 1000000 for 1MB
   - Make your wrapper script executable

     ```
     chmod +x ~/bin/wrapper
     ```
3. Restart Unity/GNOME Shell, for the GNOME Shell e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Associate one or more file types with the wrapper

   - Open your file manager and right click on a file for which the decision is to apply
   - Click <kbd>Open With Other Application</kbd>
   - Click the button <kbd>View All Applications</kbd>
   - Select the entry <kbd>File size dependent editor</kbd>
5. Enjoy **;)**

Comment: Although, why is icon not in showing like gedit icon !! Is it possible to inherit the icon of whichever editor is opened ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. The desktop file know nothing about the decision in the wrapper script. You can use a universal icon, E.g. a logger icon.

Comment: How do I do that ??

Comment: If want to use a icon from your icon theme, use the filename without an extension or use the full path for a custom icon.

Comment: But the icon specified as gedit in the wrapper file is **not working too ??**

Comment: Change the icon in the desktop file and not in the wrapper script. I have no idea which icons you have. The icon in my answer is an example.